# Do moderators take permission from OP before making a question CW?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, moderators, community-wiki

> In the past, questions could be made community wiki by their authors or by certain automatic triggers but now the only means is by a moderator converting it to community wiki.
>   <sub>~ [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741) ~</sub>

---

**Once a question is a community wiki the OP doesn't receive any reputation from it**. So do moderators take permission from the *Original Poster* or even will the OP be notified before making the post a community wiki?

Simply, can the OP prevent the question is being converted to a community wiki?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***If*** a moderator decides to switch a post to community wiki, there is nothing the OP can do to prevent that, nor are they notified.

However, we *rarely* convert a post to CW; there are simply very few reasons to do so. I'd imagine that the vast majority of cases we are responding to a flag explicitly asking for a conversion to CW.

For cases where the OP didn't ask, it would depend on the exact circumstances if we'd ask the OP if they would be okay with the change. I can't imagine a case where we'd not have consulted the OP first right now, but moderators are trusted to know when to use their toolset.